# How to reuse webpack configuration, babelrc and other configurations

Tags: git, webpack, frontend

I am facing a bit of a problem which I would like to automate but am not sure what is the easiest way to do it.

I have a repository containing a modern front end scaffolding with Webpack configuration. Looks like this:

[image: webpack config repo and other configurations]

Now as you can see this repo contains webpack configuration as well as a sample folder structure and other configurations.

My question is this: How do I utilize the repo in other projects to help me  get up and running faster and if I make an update to my webpack-config repo how do I make all my projects utilizing the configuration aware of the update ?

Do I publish the webpack-config as a NPM package ? Or do I have to make some Git sorcery ?

Thank you very much !